# Are cookies used to request image sources in android webview?

Tags: php, android, cookies, webview, android-webview

I am using an android `WebView` to load a company page which requires a certain cookie.

Part of this page are several images which are generated via PHP script. This script is on the same site and also requires the same cookie. 
I use the CookieSyncManager and CookieManager but I don't know how to  prove that the correct cookies are used.

My problem is that the pictures are not shown. When I try to access the pictures separately I get a redirect to the login page ( which is standard for not authenticated requests )

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you try on Android 4.4, you can use Dev Tools to inspect the network requests and check for the cookie. Prior to 4.4, you could try using tcpdump/wireshark to look at the requests. Alternatively, can you have the server log the cookies that are sent with the request and inspect them that way?

Comment: Can you share what the problem was and what particular suggestion helped?